# How can I automatically format en entire table that I have scraped?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, web-scraping

If I have scraped a 250 row table from Wikipedia and it needs to be updated every day, how can I do this automatically? I also need to format it and remove certain rows and columns (the top 2 rows which always stay the same, and the last column, which always stays the same). Overall there are 5 columns.

How do I scrape this data using BeautifulSoup, get all the data (minus what I said above) and place it into a differently formatted HTML table? I wasn't sure if I should use JS or...?

**Please comment if you need more information. I will reply within 5-10 mins.**

So far, I have this:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/xurl")
data = url.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table',id="thetable")
```

Comment: Please post the code snippet that you have tried in order for others to help. To update the code everyday you would have to run a scheduler that does the job.

Comment: or just have python scrape it every x seconds and then have js run code on window load